# Iterating over a dictionary (follow up to previous question)

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

Hello i am new to python and i am building a small program that returns false if a string is an isogram (words with no repeating letters consecutive or non-consecutive), and false otherwise.
It also ignores letter case.

So far i have initilised an empty dictionary which will store key value pairs containing the letter (as the key) and its frequency (the value)
Then I iterated with a for loop and in each iteration, the dictionary would be updated with the letter and its count.
If it  already have the letter, then it would increment the key value by 1, else it would remain initialised as 1.

```
def is_isogram(string):
  dict = {}
  for letter in string.lower():
    #if we have the letter
    if letter in dict:
        dict[letter] += 1
    # if we don't have the letter
    else:
        dict[letter] = 1
```

Now for me to actually determine wheather its an isogram or not i looped over the dictionary keys, and wrote a condition.
However, it keeps giving me the exact opposite output.

```
  for values in dict:
    if dict[values] > 1:
      return False 
    else:
      return True
```

OUTPUT: True

I also tried list comprehensions and lambdas but i keep getting the same result, I get True everytime.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost welcome to Python! I took a look and it seems like the issue  is occurring in your second code section, the for-loop over the dictionary values.

Adding a print statement within the loop may help debugging these sorts of things in the future, i.e.

```
for values in dict:
    print(values)
    if dict[values] > 1:
      return False 
    else:
      return True
```

HINT: This should show you that you are only looking at the first letter in any given string and returned prematurely! To fix this, you need to move the "return True" section until you are *done* checking every letter in the string.

Fixing this should get your code working as intended! Additionally, as you get further into Python you may discover that there are many ways to approach the same problem. For this one in particular, a more 'efficient' or 'elegant' approach can be found [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/collection/python-collections-counter), but again, there's many different ways to solve any problem.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'll definitely look into the more "elegant" approach. Really appreciate it.